# How can I create Azure AD B2C resource programmatically?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-rm-template, infrastructure-as-code

After I had to rebuild **Azure AD B2C** a few times following the [manual creation process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant) on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant), I want to automate the process. Is there a programmatic way to create tenants, applications, user flows etc...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To create Azure AD B2C tenant programmatically, you can make use of **Azure Management REST API**.

Note that, user or service principal should have either **`Tenant Creator`** or **`Global Administrator`** role to create tenants.

I registered one Azure AD application and added **API permission** like below:

[image]

Now I generated **access token** using Delegated flow like username password via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:password
client_id:<appID>
client_secret:<secret>
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
username: user1@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password: xxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

To create Azure AD B2C tenant, I ran below **REST API call** via Postman by including above access token like this:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subID>/resourceGroups/<rg_name>/providers/Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories/sridemoaadb2c.onmicrosoft.com?api-version=2023-01-18-preview

{
  "location": "United States",
  "sku": {
    "name": "Standard",
    "tier": "A0"
  },
  "properties": {
    "createTenantProperties": {
      "displayName": "SriDemoB2C",
      "countryCode": "US",
      "isGoLocalTenant": true
    }
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, **B2C tenant** created successfully like below:

[image]

To create applications or user flows in B2C tenant programmatically, you can make use of **Microsoft Graph API**.

**Reference:**
[Manage resources with Microsoft Graph - Azure AD B2C | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations)

Comment: Once you've created the new B2C tenant, how do you then programmatically obtain an access token for Microsoft Graph given there doesn't exist any App Registrations in the new tenant, and therefore no client_id (nor client_secret) to use in the token request?